# Coupon Codes in order overview

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

Where can i see the the coupon code the customer entered when placing an order? And why doesn't lexware get the discount? When i'm getting the invoices, there is no coupon code or discount.

Comment: On your invoice at the bottom where the total is there should be mention of the discount code

Comment: It is written, that a code was used, but not the code itself. And on my invoice created by lexware, there is no discount regarded.

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Copy

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
```

to

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
```

and the line `$page = $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);` in the getPdf function. 
This was line 107 for me.
Add the following:

```
/* print coupon code on invoice */
if($order->getCouponCode()!=""){
    $this->y -= 12;
    $page->drawText('Coupon Used: '.$order->getCouponCode(), 450, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

    /* print gift certificate code on invoice */
    if($order->getGiftcertCode()!=""){
        $this->y -= 12;
        $page->drawText('Coupon Used: '.$order->getGiftcertCode(), 450, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```